# Returning a Static Readonly List

Tags: c#, list, static

I have a class with a private static `List<String>` collection. Now I want to return a readonly list. Would this be the ideal way of doing it? Would you do it another way? Is this the proper way?

```
namespace Test
{
    static class Storage
    {

        private static List<string> store;

        static Storage()
        {
            store = new List<string>();
        }

        //Is it okay to have a getter in my static class to return my List Collection
        public static System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string>getList
        {
            get
            {
                return stores.AsReadOnly();
            }
        }

        public static void addString(string add)
        {
            store.Add(add);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Other than a lot of unnecessary line breaks, I don't see anything wrong with your code.  What are you concerned about?

Comment: @DStanley - You _can_ edit those away, you know?

Comment: I was wondering if I implemeted this right, and secondly if using ReadOnlyCollection is the ideal way of returning a readonly List collection.

Comment: @Oded - Yes I know - just venting personal pet peeves :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on client expectations. If your clients expect that the contents of the list can change, then that's (vaguely) okay. If they're expecting an *unchanging* collection, then you'll need to take a copy.

Note that `List<T>` isn't thread-safe to start with, which is a big red warning light when it comes to *global* mutable state, accessed with no obvious synchronization...

(Having global mutable state is an issue to start with, IMO, affecting testability etc. Doing so in an unsafe way just makes it even worse.)

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I would I go about making this thread safe?

Comment: Out of interest Jon would you use locks, ConcurrentBag<T> or another way to make it threadsafe?

Comment: Lock the store when adding a new string:

lock(store) { store.Add(add); }.